# Swift - Large to Small Title Transition

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem, preferslargetitles

I'm currently implementing a very simple TableViewController that has a navigation bar.

I have set the title, turned the navigation bar `translucent = true` , and turned `PrefersLargeTitles = true`

Large Title is set to `Automatic` on the Navigation Item

When scrolling in the table view, the title switches from large to small as I would expect, but there is a hiccup in the transition.

When I look at the native settings app on an iPhone, the transition is very smooth from large to small titles, and not here.

Is there some setting I am missing to animate / smooth this transition?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Where are you setting the title on the TableViewController? viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear?

Comment: @userx viewDidLoad

Comment: Could you please add image?

Comment: You may want to try it in viewWillAppear.

Comment: Could you add a video/animated gif of the transition the way it appears for you?

Answer (score 2):

In your viewController set `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars` to `true`. Also set `edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.all`

Comment: I tried this originally as it's what Apple suggests doing. However, this doesn't work when you have UITableView inside of a UIViewController

Comment: I also added `edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.all` and it worked for my tableView in a UIViewController (all done programmatically). Were you able to get it to work at any point?